# Page not found error when using plus"+" sign in the path aliases

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pathauto, drupal-path-aliases

I am trying to create a new simple node with url alias as `test+node`. when i save the node the page is not showing the node, the url changes as

`http://server/packets/test%2Bnode`

but it only shows the following error

`Page not found
The requested page "/packets/test%2Bnode" could not be found.`

Can anyone help me to fix this issue out...

Answer (score 0):

Drupal want's to stop the "+" character from being a space. Drupal encodes the character and can't recognize the URL alias.

See this thread here: 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125156/page-not-found-error-when-using-plus-sign-in-the-url-alias

Its probably better to avoid using characters like "+" in aliases, 
but maybe try adding this to your .htaccess file, with clean URL's enabled:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  %2B 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA,NE]
```